GITHUB_TOKEN permission in workflow changes to read after setting it to write
I am trying to write a workflow that will automatically merge pull requests to a public repository on GitHub:
name: X
on:
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - '<path>'

jobs:
  Y:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
    env:
      Approve: true
      ADDED_FILES_COUNT: ""
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - id: automerge
        name: automerge
        uses: "pascalgn/automerge-action@v0.16.3"
        env:
            GITHUB_TOKEN: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
            MERGE_LABELS: ""

Notice I change the permissions on contents to write.
Still, looking at the run on GitHub Actions the persmission is set to read:

As result, when automerge is called an error message is shown and merging fails:

I already changed the project settings to those:

Why it is happening? Is PAT a must in this case?

If you set the workflow permission in the repo settings, that's like setting permissions: write-all, except for Dependabot PRs, which default to read-only. It's also less secure than setting explicit permissions.
But if you do set explicit permissions, all scopes that you don't mention are set to read permissions.
You set contents: write, so everything else is read-only. To merge a PR, your token needs pull-requests: write permissions.
I would set that, and then I recommend switching back to read-only defaults in the repo settings.
Additionally, as it turned out from comments, when PRs come from a public fork, GITHUB_TOKEN defaults to read-only permissions; the workaround here is to use pull_request_target instead of pull_request. This can make you vulnerable to security issues, as you potentially merge unreviewed third-party code.

Thank you for answering. I changed the file to have pull-requests: write and it is also returns to read in github actions. still fails to merge. i don't understand why both contents and pull-requests are set as read on github actions if i set them in the workflow to write

@EyalBrilling This is very odd. Even if there were an org-level setting for read-only defaults, the explicit settings in the workflow should override it. Is the trigger you show the one you actually use? And are the workflows triggered by you, or some automation?

The workflow is triggered when a user opens a pull request on github, it is the one i use. besided github actions i don't use anything else - it auto trigges by github(i guess?). When i try to re-run the workflow manually in github, permission is still 'read'

@EyalBrilling Is the repo public, per chance, and if so, could you link to it?

Yes this is the project: https://github.com/UrielOfir/os-practice

@EyalBrilling Ah, I see the issue. Because your PRs come from a public fork, GITHUB_TOKEN only has read permissions (see here). You might be able to get write permissions by using pull_request_target as the trigger. Make sure to explicitly check out he PR head, and not the base; see https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26874#discussioncomment-3253755
